# XSLT - Split a quote into list

Tags: xml, xslt

I have string as `"Aircraft Crash" "Aircraft Hijacking" Avalanche Flood`

I can output it as:

```
<item>Aircraft Crash</item>
<item>Aircraft Hijacking</item>
<item>Avalanche</item>
<item>Flood</item>
```

example: https://gist.github.com/netsi1964/2648824

But how can I produce `["Aircraft Crash", "Aircraft Hijacking", "Avalanche", "Flood"]` using XSLT 1.0?

```
<alert xmlns="xxxxxxxxxxxx">
    <identifier>203.81.87.42--20160621-583-</identifier>
    <sender>12.12.4</sender>
    <sent>2016-06-21T05:17:02+00:00</sent>
    <status>Test</status>
   <incidents>
       "Aircraft Crash" "Aircraft Hijacking" Avalanche Flood
   </incidents>
</alert>
```

to

```
<s3xml success="true">
    <resource name="cap_alert" uuid="urn:uuid:b5305e2b-9aa6-45ae-bb34-ed777cedbc3a" created_by="admin@example.com">
        <data field="identifier">203.81.87.42--20160621-583-</data>
        <data field="incidents" value="["Aircraft Crash", "Aircraft Hijacking", "Avalanche", "Flood"]">
Aircraft Crash, Aircraft Hijacking, Avalanche, Flood
        </data>
        <data field="sender">12.12.4</data>
        <data field="sent" value="2016-06-21T05:17:02">June 21, 2016 12:17:02</data>
        <data field="status" value=""Test"">Test - testing, all recipients disregard</data>
   </resource>
</s3xml>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="xxxxxxxxxxxx">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<!-- ****************************************************************** -->
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="s3xml"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- ****************************************************************** -->
<xsl:template match="/s3xml">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./resource[@name='cap_alert']"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- ****************************************************************** -->
<xsl:template match="resource[@name='cap_alert']">

    <alert>
        <identifier>
            <xsl:value-of select="data[@field='identifier']"/>
        </identifier>

        <sender>
            <xsl:value-of select="data[@field='sender']"/>
        </sender>

        <status>
            <xsl:value-of select="translate(data[@field='status']/@value, '&quot;', '')"/>
        </status>
        <incidents>??????</incidents>
    </alert>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you wish to re-purpose the xsl in github so that it processes your initial space-delimited string to produce the json array output?

Comment: What is your execution environment - do you even need to be using xsl for such a simple string conversion?

Comment: Yes I am using XSL for this usecase. The string usually comes in the above format - space-delimited if single word else quotation delimited.
`Input: This is "a string" . 
output: ["This", "is", "a string"]
Input: "Aircraft Crash" "Aircraft Hijacking" Avalanche Flood
Output: ["Aircraft Crash", "Aircraft Hijacking", "Aircraft Hijacking", "Flood"]`

Comment: so your input is just a string not xml? If its a plain string then your use case is wrong to recommend xsl. If its xml, please provide a example of the xml input in the question.

Comment: @BiplovBhandari Why is `Avalanche` missing from your output? P.S. Please don't post code in comments.Edit your question and put **all** relevant information there in full (not links). I also don't see how the linked stylesheet produces the claimed output.

Comment: @BiplovBhandari Show us at least how you call the `splitStringToItems` template to produce the 4 `item` elements you say you can output.

Comment: I will..Please give me some time, I am out for dinner :)

Comment: @michael.hor257k just edited the question..have a look!

Comment: I still don't see how you would produce the output that you say you can. I don't think the stylesheet you have linked to can do it, but if you know how, then show us - because it would require only a small adjustment to produce the output you want.

Comment: @michael.hor257k done.please see

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will create a variable with the desired content, you still have to put it at the right place:

```
<xsl:variable name="Array">
    <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="item">
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()"><xsl:text>, </xsl:text></xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: This gives me "Aircraft Crash" "Aircraft Hijacking" Avalanche Flood
Notice no commas

Comment: No idea...It was not when I checked it. Anyway I think for-each treat whole string as single so basically I get the same result which is not wanted!

Comment: Which compiler you are using? And can you post the XSLT?

Comment: XSLT. I don't think it makes much sense to post XSLT here as this is way too big.

Comment: Then just the part which handles the items

Comment: That XSLT is what I need

Comment: I meant the XSLT part from your XSLT surrounding the function you need... the part where you handle items.

Comment: These go directly to database as list:string in Python

Answer (score 0):

The following template will split your space-delimeted string into a set of <value/> nodes

```
    <xsl:template name="split">
        <xsl:param name="string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="testString" select="normalize-space($string)"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$testString=''"/>
            <xsl:when test="contains($testString,'&quot;') and substring-before($testString,'&quot;')=''">
                <xsl:variable name="afterQuote" select="substring-after($testString,'&quot;')"/>
                <xsl:variable name="quotedString" select="substring-before($afterQuote,'&quot;')"/>
                <value><xsl:value-of select="$quotedString"/></value>
                <xsl:call-template name="split">
                    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($afterQuote,'&quot;')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="substring-before($testString,' ')">
                <value><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($testString,' ')"/></value>
                <xsl:call-template name="split">
                    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($testString,' ')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <value><xsl:value-of select="$testString"/></value>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

Now with the values as a nodeset you can work with it to produce whatever output you require.  In your case you will use it something like this...

```
<xsl:template match="incidents">

    <xsl:variable name="incidentset">
        <xsl:call-template name="split">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- at this point $incidentset will be a fragment:
         <value>Aircraft Crash</value>
         <value>Aircraft Hijacking</value>
         <value>Avalanche</value>  
        <value>Flood</value>
    --> 
    <data field="incidents" >
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
            <!-- many xsl processors required $incidentset to be converted into node-set, mine doesn't!-->
            <xsl:for-each select="$incidentset/*">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;',text(),'&quot;')" disable-output-escaping="no"/>
                <xsl:if test="position()!=last()"><xsl:text>,</xsl:text></xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <!-- many xsl processors required $incidentset to be converted into node-set, mine doesn't!-->
        <xsl:for-each select="$incidentset/*">
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()"><xsl:text>,</xsl:text></xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </data>

</xsl:template>
```

Note that some xsl processors will require you to convert the fragement into a workable node-set.  See http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/07/16/nodeset.html for examples on how to do that.