# XSL 1.0 comma delimited row to xml

Tags: xml, csv, xslt-1.0

I have txt file as below:

```
<raw>
Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4,Value5,"Paris,France"
</raw>
```

And wanted to convert as

```
<raw>
<column>Value1</column>
<column>Value2</column>
<column>Value3</column>
<column>Value4</column>
<column>Value5</column>
<column>Paris,France</column>
</raw>
```

I just started learning xslt and I am not sure how split the row by delimiter and to escape the double quote.
This is what I have so far.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:lxslt="http://xml.apache.org/xslt" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" xmlns:redirect="org.apache.xalan.lib.Redirect" extension-element-prefixes="redirect" exclude-result-prefixes="xalan">
    <xsl:template match="RawData">
        <RawData>
            <xsl:for-each select="row">
                <column><xsl:value-of select="row/column[1]"/></column>
                <column><xsl:value-of select="row/column[2]"/></column>
                <column><xsl:value-of select="row/column[3]"/></column>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </RawData>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a trivial problem - certainly not suitable for someone who has just started learning XSLT.

This is how I would approach it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="normalize-space(raw)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="','"/>
    <xsl:variable name="token">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="substring($text, 1, 1) = '&quot;'">
                 <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($text, '&quot;'), '&quot;')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space($token)">         
        <token>
            <xsl:value-of select="$token"/>
        </token>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="substring($text, 1, 1) = '&quot;'">
                         <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after($text, '&quot;'), '&quot;')"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that this does not handle escaped quotes.

---

There are some alternative methods suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37938253/xslt-split-a-quote-into-list); I haven't tested them.

Comment: Is there a way to split the result by row?

Comment: Yes: you need to tokenize by newline first, then send each token to be tokenized further as shown above. If (as it seems) you are using Xalan, you can use the EXSLT str:tokenize() or str:split() extension functions to do the initial split by row.